# htaccess various rewriting needs

Tags: file, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, directory

I have a website let's say http://myweb.com and I want to migrate it into a subfolder of the root directory http://myweb.com/subfolder/

I need the following things, I guess using the htaccess file:

1) Redirect all non-www to www
2) Redirect all files in the root to equivalent files in the subfolder at the same time changing all htm extension to html, that is a file in the root file.htm must be rewritten to a file in the subfolder like subfolder/file.html
3)I want that in the address is still displayed www.myweb.com rather than www.myweb.com/subfolder

is it all possible? And how? Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these rules to the htaccess in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# 1) Redirect all non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# 2) Redirect all files in the root to equivalent files in the subfolder
#    at the same time changing all htm extension to html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /subfolder/$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

The last rules don't have the `R` flag so they won't cause an external redirect (thus changing what's in the browser's URL address bar).

Comment: Hello Jon, Thanks for your answer. Seems it's working except I see the new address in the browser still. Also can you advice a way to redirect to a certain page if the page is not found in the subfolder?

Comment: I have found some more problems. Seems like in ie9 the non-www to www does not work if I type in the address: http://myweb.com/ but in firefox it works. Strange enough in IE9 the url is kept in the address though while in firefox it is not. I am puzzled!